# How to use both fontawesome and fontawesome5?

Tags: font-encodings, icon

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, scheme = plain]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} %% Virus / fancyAT
\usepackage{fontawesome} %% faWechat
\begin{document}
\faIcon{virus}
\faAt 
\faWechat 
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use all the symbols from the two packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\faWechat` is an alias for `\faWeixin` in `fontawesome`  (Weixin is the (original) Chinese name for the app that is known as WeChat outside China), the latter is also in `fontawesome5`, you should not need to load both.

Comment: No wonder... Thanks!